# How to only allow one space in an InputField?

Tags: unity, c#, gui, input

I've been messing with this for a while now and I can't get this to work 100%. I'm using an InputField for players to enter a character name, and I want to allow a first and last name. Here's how I've been trying this:

```
private void CharNameRestrictions() {
    Debug.Log(spaceCount);

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)) {
        spaceCount++;
        if (spaceCount > 1) {
            spaceCount = 1;
            playerNameInput.text = playerNameInput.text.Remove(playerNameInput.text.Length - 1);
        }
    }

    if (!(playerNameInput.text.Contains(" "))) spaceCount = 0;
    if (playerNameInput.text.Length > 15) playerNameInput.text = playerNameInput.text.Remove(playerNameInput.text.Length - 1);

}
```

This sort of works, but if you press and hold space while typing another character, it still lets you add additional spaces. Is there a way to simply ignore the space keycode when there is already a space in the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script suffers of many drawbacks. Nothing prevent the user from moving the caret at the beginning of the inputfield and add a space.

Here is a script I made for you which seems to work. However, it's quite frustrating to not see any result of a user input action.

Instead of deleting the character, I would suggest to outline the inputfield with a red color.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CheckInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Drag & Drop your inputfield in the following Inspector field
    [SerializeField]
    private InputField inputField ;

    private Regex regex ;

    private string validValue ;

    private void Awake()
    {
        regex = new Regex( @"^[a-z\-]+ [a-z\-]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        inputField.onValueChanged.AddListener( OnInputFieldValueChanged );
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        inputField.onValueChanged.RemoveListener( OnInputFieldValueChanged );
    }

    private void OnInputFieldValueChanged( string newValue )
    {
        int index = newValue.IndexOf(' ');
        int length = newValue.Length;

        if ( index < 0 || index == length - 1 )
        {
            validValue = newValue;
            return;
        }
        else if ( regex.IsMatch( newValue ) && length <= 15 )
        {
            validValue = newValue;
        }
        else
        {
            inputField.text = validValue;
        }
    }
}
```