# Disable spaces in InputField

Tags: unity, c#, input

This is straight forward. I have an input field and I want to restrict the user of inputting any spaces. I was thinking to make a script that checks if the user typed in a space and then remove it, but is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Change the font of that input field, don't include the space ASCII character code in the font import file. So that means setting the offset to 33. That should be it for not letting the user see space inputs.

Of course, they will still be inputting spaces (just not seeing them) but you can filter them out when they send the string for whatever you need it for. I don't really have time to test this right now but if you do let me know and I'll do the same if I test it.

Comment: @Leon Laci : Have you even tried to make some research ? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/134541/how-to-only-allow-one-space-in-an-inputfield/134554#134554

Comment: I'm still new to unity and c# so I don't understand most of the code and how to use it in my case, but I will try to make it work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy solution IF you only require alphanumeric characters (alphanumeric characters include: a-z,A-Z,0-9). In the input field, change the content type to alphanumeric. This will only allow letters and numbers, not spaces.

[image: content type]

You can also try out the other options too.
Otherwise, if you require symbols too, you will have to use a script with a checking function that removes spaces. This would be initiated by the On Value Changed, which you can also se in the image.

I can quickly code an example script if you want me to.

EDIT:
OK, I have made an example script and will show you how to use On Value Changed.
Start by making a new c# script called 'UpdateInputField' and replace the text with this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;// this is needed to use the 'InputField' 

public class UpdateInputField : MonoBehaviour
{
    InputField IF;
    void Start()
    {
        IF = GetComponent<InputField>();//get the input field
    }
    public void UpdateField()
    {
        string text = IF.text;//get text from input field
        text=text.Replace(" ","");//fliter spaces from text
        IF.text = text;//set the text in the input field to the filtered text
    }
}
```

Go and add this script to the input field object.
Next, click on the + sign on 'On Value Changed':
Then click on the bottom left box. In the window that appears, find the input field object in your scene and select it.

[image: next]

After that, click on the top right box and select UpdateInputField, UpdateField()

[image]

And that should be it!
The OnValueChanged part automatically calls the UpdateField() function in the script whenever the input field is typed into. The UpdateField() function will then filter any spaces from the text and then set the text in the input field to the filtered text.

Comment: I don't know how the on value change works, I was first thinking making a update method that checks if there are empty spaces.

Comment: @Gnemlock I have updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 2):

My solution to disable 'tab' symbol in input field. You can disable any other symbols

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ConsoleInputController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private InputField consoleInputField;
   
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void Start()
    {
        consoleInputField = GameObject.Find("ConsoleInputField").GetComponent<InputField>();
        // Sets the DisableTabValidate method to invoke after the input field's default input validation invoke (default validation happens every time a character is entered into the text field.)
        consoleInputField.onValidateInput += delegate(string input, int charIndex, char addedChar) { return DisableTabValidate(addedChar); };
    }

    private char DisableTabValidate(char charToValidate)
     {
         //Checks if a tab sign is entered....
         if (charToValidate == '\t')
         {
             // ... if it is change it to an empty character.
             charToValidate = '\0';
         }
         return charToValidate;
     }
}
```